# ORACLE db become very very slow while updating the particular table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Our company database has a table named as "TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE". It has about more then 600000 records this time and also system adds about 3500 records each day for employee attendance records. So when we do the process of attendance calculations then whole database as well as application becomes too slow and takes about 2.5 to 3 hrs for each shift. What can we do to faster the processing?

[image]

**TABLE DESCRIPTION:**

```
CREATE TABLE SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (
  CM_CODE NUMBER(2, 0) NOT NULL,
  EAE_MONTH NUMBER(2, 0) NOT NULL,
  EAE_YEAR NUMBER(4, 0) NOT NULL,
  EAE_EM_ID NUMBER(8, 0) NOT NULL,
  EAE_EMP_ID VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  EAE_REG_NO VARCHAR2(6 BYTE),
  EM_NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  EAE_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
  EM_TYPE_CODE NUMBER(4, 0),
  EG_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  PH_CODE NUMBER(4, 0),
  DEPT_CODE NUMBER(4, 0),
  SUBDEPT_CODE NUMBER(4, 0),
  SHIFT_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  SCH_INTIME TIMESTAMP(6),
  SCH_OUTTIME TIMESTAMP(6),
  IN_TIME TIMESTAMP(6),
  OUT_TIME TIMESTAMP(6),
  DAY NUMBER(5, 2),
  LATE_TIME NUMBER(15, 2),
  OVER_TIME NUMBER(15, 2),
  EAE_EM_RESTDAY VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  DAILY_STATUS VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  LTM_CODE NUMBER(4, 0),
  BMANUALUPDATEINOUTTIME NUMBER(1, 0),
  TOTAL_PUNCH NUMBER(3, 0),
  REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEMREMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64KREMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITEDREMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEMREMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64KREMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITEDREMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (EAE_EM_ID, CM_CODE, EAE_DATE)REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (EAE_EM_ID, CM_CODE, EAE_DATE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEMREMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (EAE_EM_ID, CM_CODE, EAE_DATE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (EAE_EM_ID, CM_CODE, EAE_DATE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64KREMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (EAE_EM_ID, CM_CODE, EAE_DATE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITEDREMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (EAE_EM_ID, CM_CODE, EAE_DATE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)REMARK VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
  WORK_HOURS NUMBER(4, 2),
  ENT_DATE DATE,
  USER_ID NUMBER(8, 0),
  DM_ID NUMBER(4, 0),
  LATE_GOING NUMBER(15, 2),
  DAY_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CONSTRAINT TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE_O_PK PRIMARY KEY (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EAE_MONTH, EAE_YEAR) USING INDEX TABLESPACE SYSTEM STORAGE ( INITIAL 64K MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED ))
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY2_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (CM_CODE, EAE_EM_ID, EAE_DATE, EM_TYPE_CODE, EG_ID, DEPT_CODE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYSTEM.IND_TEMP_DAILY_O ON SYSTEM.TEMP_EMP_ATTENDANCE (EAE_EM_ID, CM_CODE, EAE_DATE)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;
```

Comment: `What can we do to faster the processing?` You can tune the processing - the processing probably uses several different queries -,you should identify which query takes the most time, tune this query, then identify the next slovest query and tune it too, and so on and so on, until the whole processing will be fast enough. Maybe the code of the processing must be rewriten somehow. No one can tell you without looking at the code. I vote to close this question as too broad.

Comment: Something has gone wrong with your 400+ line DDL dump as it is full of `remark` lines and repetition. If you limited it to details relevant to the question it might be clearer.

Comment: How are the rows inserted? If it's `insert /*+ append */` or a direct path load utility that might explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all its a bad design to use "SYSTEM" user account to have user data and you are creating your table on SYSTEM tablespace.  You should have another user which should own your objects on different tablespace.  You should not keep any user data on "SYSTEM TABLESPACE" .

Now coming to make your query execution fast there are several parameters which you need to consider.

To start with :

1. Check if you have updated stats on table and indexes. if your stats are stale then this could be main reason so  update the stats on table. If stats are not stale then check when was this table last_analyzed. If  there is change in data more than ~10% in that table since last analyzed then gather the stats on table.
2. check if you have high fragmentation on that table. If yes then consider rebuilding it.
3. If your table size is very huge then try to implement partitions concept on that table.
4. Check OS resource utilization while your report is running. Do you sufficient RAM,CPU to fulfill you query. (free -m,  vmstat 1 10 , iostat -c 1 10)
5. AWR reports are best to analyze what is happening to your database. When you start generating report note down the time and then once it is finished then note down time and generate AWR report. If time duration is more than 1 hour then generate AWR 1 hour interval.  You can easily find out what is happening with your database.

These are generic approach which anyone can follow. Still there are many parameters which can be fetch out from AWR report .